# Validate two column values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to validate two column values - if the values are true then it should display alert message.

```
Sub sal() 
Dim a As Long 
Dim b As Long 
a = Range("x3", Range("x3").End(xlDown)).Value 
b = Range("w3", Range("w3").End(xlDown)).Value 
If a = 100 And b <> " " Then MsgBox "already acheived" 
End If 
End Sub
```

It is showing runtime error 13.

Comment: If your error is on the `If` statement, it is because you have declared `b` to be numeric (type `Long`) but then try to compare it to `" "` (a `String`).  You also have an `End If` without a corresponding `If`, but that might just be how the code was pasted into the question (i.e. maybe the `MsgBox` is on a different line to the `If`).

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a and b as long and they are supposed to hold one value of long datatype.

But in the following lines of code...

```
a = Range("x3", Range("x3").End(xlDown)).Value 
b = Range("w3", Range("w3").End(xlDown)).Value
```

You are trying to assign values of a range with multiple cells to both of them.

You should use it like this...

```
a = Range("x3").Value
b = Range("w3").Value
```

Also as YowE3L has mentioned, check the variable b like this...

```
b <> 0
```

Comment: I completely overlooked the multi-cell ranges when I was looking for errors - well spotted!

Comment: And I missed the other two parts you pointed out. So it was a perfect team work. :)

Comment: I suspect the single-line -v- block `If` issue might be just in the question, not in the original code.  (The last line in the question was originally `End If End Sub` before my edit, but I spotted that and split it because it was obviously impossible - so the other line might be just a similar issue.)

Comment: Yes. That's also another point you raised. Actually the End If there makes no sense. I think you should have removed that line when edited the question. :)

Comment: It would make sense if it's actually a block-If, i.e. `If a = 100 And b <> " " Then` / `MsgBox "already acheived"` / `End If`.  (Personally, I always use block-Ifs even when it's a very simple statement - I just find it easier to read than a single-line If.)

Comment: Same here. I also include an IF block instead of single line IF statement. :)